# Problem with pam_mount and sshfs

Tags: debian, ssh, pam, sshfs

I'm trying to configure automounting of users home directories using `pam_mount` and sshfs (users are LDAP users on remote machine).

I configured `pam_mount`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pam_mount SYSTEM "pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd">
<pam_mount>
<debug enable="1" />
<mntoptions allow="nosuid,nodev,loop,encryption,fsck,nonempty,allow_root,allow_other" />
<mntoptions require="nosuid,nodev" />
<logout wait="0" hup="0" term="0" kill="0" />
<mkmountpoint enable="1" remove="true" />
<volume fstype="fuse" path="sshfs#%(USER)@HOSTNAME:" mountpoint="~" ssh="1" options="reconnect,idmap=user,password_stdin,nonempty" />
</pam_mount>
```

When I'm trying to `su` to user I'm asked about password:

```
root@debian:~# su - pszubert
pam_mount(pam_mount.c:553): pam_mount 2.5: entering session stage
reenter password for pam_mount:
pam_mount(misc.c:38): Session open: (ruid/rgid=0/20001, e=0/20001)
pam_mount(mount.c:213): Mount info: globalconf, user=pszubert <volume fstype="fuse" server="(null)" path="sshfs#pszubert@HOST:" mountpoint="/home/pszubert" cipher="(null)" fskeypath="(null)" fskeycipher="(null)" fskeyhash="(null)" options="reconnect,idmap=user,password_stdin,nonempty" /> fstab=0 ssh=1
command: 'pmt-fd0ssh' 'mount.fuse' 'sshfs#pszubert@HOST:' '/home/pszubert' '-oreconnect,idmap=user,password_stdin,nonempty' 
pam_mount(spawn.c:108): setting uid to user pszubert
pam_mount(misc.c:38): set_myuid<post>: (ruid/rgid=20001/20001, e=20001/20001)
System plików  Typ bl.  1K B        użyte dostępne %uż. zamont. na
/dev/sda1     ext3     7867856    940236   6527956  13% /
tmpfs        tmpfs      192316         0    192316   0% /lib/init/rw
proc          proc           0         0         0   -  /proc
sysfs        sysfs           0         0         0   -  /sys
udev         tmpfs      187872       148    187724   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs      192316         0    192316   0% /dev/shm
devpts      devpts           0         0         0   -  /dev/pts
fusectl    fusectl           0         0         0   -  /sys/fs/fuse/connections
pam_mount(pam_mount.c:521): mount of sshfs#pszubert@HOST: failed
command: 'pmvarrun' '-u' 'pszubert' '-o' '1' 
pam_mount(misc.c:38): set_myuid<pre>: (ruid/rgid=0/20001, e=0/20001)
pam_mount(misc.c:38): set_myuid<post>: (ruid/rgid=0/20001, e=0/20001)
pmvarrun(pmvarrun.c:248): parsed count value 0
pam_mount(pam_mount.c:440): pmvarrun says login count is 1
pam_mount(pam_mount.c:643): done opening session (ret=0)
```

In HOST `auth.log` there is info:

```
Mar 17 22:13:42 student sshd[17889]: Accepted password for pszubert from 85.202.159.212 port 20264 ssh2
Mar 17 22:13:42 student sshd[17889]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user pszubert by (uid=0)
Mar 17 22:13:42 student sshd[17891]: subsystem request for sftp
Mar 17 22:13:42 student sshd[17891]: Received disconnect from XXXXXXXXXX: 11: disconnected by user
Mar 17 22:13:42 student sshd[17889]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user pszubert
```

What is weird when I'm logged in I can mount remote fs using `sshfs pszubert@HOST: a/`.

What's wrong?

I think that problem is with `~/.ssh` on local machine. First problem was about `known_hosts` file, so I created global `known_hosts` in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`. Now `~/.ssh` is still created, but is empty even if I connect to remote host manually. I think that if I could prevent of creation `~/.ssh` it would solve problem. Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved problem.

First I created global `known_hosts` file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`.

Main problem was visible in this line of debug:

```
command: 'pmt-fd0ssh' 'mount.fuse' 'sshfs#pszubert@HOST:' '/home/pszubert' '-oreconnect,idmap=user,password_stdin,nonempty'
```

As we can see there is no space between `-o` and options.

Adding line:

```
<fusemount>mount.fuse %(VOLUME) %(MNTPT) -o %(OPTIONS)</fusemount>
```

to `pam_mount` config file (`/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml`) solved problem. Now `mount.fuse` is called in tis way this:

```
command: 'pmt-fd0ssh' 'mount.fuse' 'sshfs#pszubert@HOST:' '/home/pszubert' '-o' 'reconnect,nonempty'
```

Next important things are permissions to `/dev/fuse` and `/usr/bin/fusermount`. User should be in `fuse` group. In my case it wasn't possible because it is remote user so I changed permissions manually:

```
chmod o+x /usr/bin/fusermount
chmod o+rw /dev/fuse
```